# Codeigniter server REST

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I create a server on codeigniter rest v 2.1.1 by following this tutorial.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2--net-8814

I have an error in the file REST_Controller.php

My code:

```
<?php

require(APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Api extends REST_Controller {

    function test_get() {
    $this->response(array('success' => 'Yes it is working'), 200);
    }

}
```

My URI : ndd.com/api/test/format/json

My response :

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Creating default object from empty value</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/REST_Controller.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 41</p>

</div>{"success":"Yes it is working"}
```

Line 41 in REST_Controller.php

```
// How is this request being made? POST, DELETE, GET, PUT?
        $this->request->method = $this->_detect_method();
```

What can I do to fix the error?

Comment: https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/tree/2.6.0

Answer (score 5):

Try this code in **Rest_controller.php**

Add these line

```
if(!is_object($this->request))
         {
            $this->request= new stdClass();
         }
```

in the starting of

```
publict function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();

   $this->load->config('rest');

  //some where here like 

   if(!is_object($this->request))
         {
            $this->request= new stdClass();
         }

$this->request->method = $this->_detect_method();


......
....
...
}
```

Comment: This didn't fix the problem for me.